# "Das ist gut zu wissen" or "Gut zu wissen"?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, style

> Gut zu wissen, dass meine Familie rüber nach Kalifornien kommt, um Weihnachtsfest mit mir zu begehen.

Is *gut zu wissen* a correct translation for *good to know*?

Or can one also say it this way?

> Das ist gut zu wissen, dass meine Familie nach Kalifornien herüberkommt, um Weihnachtsfest mit mir zu begehen.

Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: ... das Weihnachtsfest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are fine. The first one sounds more colloquial, the second is more formal (very formal). Although I'd rather use

> Es ist gut zu wissen …

instead of:

> Das ist gut zu wissen …

Nevertheless, at least in spoken language I'd always go with:

> Gut zu wissen, dass …

As you have asked for alternatives: You could also say *schön* instead of *gut*, but I think that *gut* is more often used.

So, to cut a long story short: Yes, that's fine :-)

Comment: Ich würde eher "Es ist gut zu wissen" als "Das ist gut zu wissen" sagen. Bei "Das" denke ich "Was? Worauf bezieht sich das 'Das'?"